# Evento de click não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar um objeto dinâmico para um evento de click.

Toda vez que uma página for carregada, os dados que estão salvos no banco vão ser preenchidas no front.

O evento de click tem a mesma regra que o evento que verifica se o elemento está checkado assim que a página é carregada.

```
var teste = {
    testando: function(element){
        $(element).on("click",function(){    
            var valor = $(element + ":checked").val();
            this.uai(valor);    
            alert("teste");
        });

        if(($(element)).is(":checked")) {
            var valor = $(element + ":checked").val();
            this.uai(valor);
        }
    },
    uai : function(valor){
        //faz algo com o valor, como por exemplo: deixar uma div invisível ou não            
    }
};


$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".radio1").get("2").checked = true;
    teste.testando("[name='radio1']");
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9rmu2jpw/2

Answer (score 0):

Veja se eu entendi bem:

```
var teste = {};

teste.uai = function(valor){
         alert(valor);            
    };

teste.testando = function(element){    
        if(($(element)).is(":checked")) {
            var valor = $(element + ":checked").val();
            this.uai(valor);
        }
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".radio1").get("2").checked = true;
    teste.testando(".radio1:checked");
    $(".radio1").on("click",function(){                 
        var valor = $(".radio1:checked").val();
        teste.uai(valor);    
                alert("teste");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9rmu2jpw/7/

Comment: é isso, mas eu queria fazer o evento de click dentro do objeto, iria poupar um poupo de codificação (ou seja, só chamaria o "teste.testando" passando o elemento...)

Comment: Da maneira que você fez o evento do click só vai disparar quando o primeiro elemento que foi carregado na pagina como checkado for clicado. É isso mesmo que vc quer ?

Comment: eu queria que esse evento sempre fosse disparado quando o elemento fosse clicado, mas como faço funcionar usando um evento de click dentro do objeto?

Comment: Quando você usa dentro do objeto, você está usando sempre o mesmo seletor, que é "[name='radio1']", que você chama 1 vez ao carregar o documento (dentro do document.ready). Para pegar sempre o elemento que é clicado você não pode colocar esse evento de click dentro do objeto.